# Why does this hover in scss & bootstrap not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have the following Boostrap HTML:

```
      <div class="d-flex mx-2 ml-auto">
        <a href="#">
          <%= inline_svg_tag("icons/interface/heart.svg", alt: "like", class: "icon icon-lg bg-danger heart-like-icon") %>
        </a>
      </div>
```

That generates the following HTML:

```
<a href="#">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" class="icon icon-lg bg-danger heart-like-icon">
<path d="M16.5 5C14.8905 5 13.0082 6.82463 12 8C10.9918 6.82463 9.1095 5 7.5 5C4.651 5 3 7.22218 3 10.0504C3 13.1835 6 16.5 12 20C18 16.5 21 13.25 21 10.25C21 7.42177 19.349 5 16.5 5Z" fill="#212529"></path>
   </svg>    
</a>
```

The above is in my `articles/show.html.erb`.

In my `articles.scss`, I have the following:

```
.heart-like-icon {
  &:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

The `heart.svg` renders fine, but when I hover over the icon it doesn't change the opacity and when I check the element order in my developer console I don't see the `heart-like-icon:hover` style listed.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you import your styles into your HTML correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .heart-like-icon and change the "&" to "a".  your css code should only be this:

```
  a:hover {
     opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/uaL4nxd3/2/

Comment: This is SCSS, not CSS which is why it was done like that.

Comment: Ahh understood. Sorry.  For what it's worth I plugged you code exactly into https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/scss  and it worked for me.  Sorry I couldn't help you more.